# Blender 2.8 3D viewer export with texture

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, export, .fbx

When I export .fbx files and view them in the *Windows 10 3d Viewer*, they dont have the textures on them. How can I preview my .fbx files with textures in the *Windows 10 3d Viewer*?

My .fbx files work in unity as usual, because I import them without textures and add the textures in unity.
With 2.79 I would my object as .fbx and the UV map as an image and in the *Windows 10 3d Viewer* my object had the texture on it. There was some function like *apply texture*.
When exporting from 2.8 (with the same steps) the 3D viewer does not show any texture on my models.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, Felix. I have edited your question to make it better readable, can you confirm that I have not altered it's meaning. I don't understand the main question. What 3D viewer are you refering to? Are you trying to export an FBX from Blender 2.8 and it is missing textures?

Comment: Thank you for your help, my english isnt the best. I mean the standard windows 3D viewer. With 2.79 I could easily export my object as .fbx + the UV map as an image and in the 3D viewer my object had the texture on it. There was some function like "apply texture". Now with 2.8 i export the object as a .fbx file and the UV map but in the 3D viewer it does not have any texture on it.

Comment: Your comment made it clear to me. I have tried to add the information from your comment to the question. Unfortunately I can't help you, since I have never used the windows 3D viewer. Good luck! Feel free to add information to your question by editing when you have new ideas.

Comment: Can you recommend any software for a preview or for showing the fbx to other people?

Comment: Blender is pretty good, otherwise the is Autodesks [FBX Review](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/fbx-review).

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try it.

Comment: Update: I figured it out. Somehow my applied texture was broken or smth. I recreated my object and not only saved the UV map but also packed it to the blendfile like I used to in 2.79. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your texture into the folder where your fbx file is.

[image]

In the image I am in UV Editing

Comment: Thats what I have already done.